# Architecture of a secure client-server phonegap app

Tags: security, cordova, client-server

I am thinking about the architecture of a phonegap game app which, as lots of ditributed game app, will act as a client of a server. It will need username-password authentification. I plan to use AJAX to communicate with my server. However, I have a couple of questions concerning security. Here they are:

1. How can I make sure the request is made from my game and not by anyone else ? For example, how to avoid that somebody can send a POST request to the script on the server called by my game ?
2. How can I secure data transfer ? Is data transfer using a https (SSL) url sufficient ?
3. What is the best idea to implement user authentication ? Generate a token to use in communication ? Something else ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

> 1) How can I make sure the request is made from my game and not by anyone else ? For example, how to avoid that somebody can send a POST
>   request to the script on the server called by my game ?

Unfortunately, you can't.  Because you have no control over the client code once it leaves your hands, there is no way to ensure that no one else is making requests using the login credentials of your users (assuming there are some).  You can ensure that certain users are accessing your server by requiring them to authenticate.  As long as they don't compromise their credentials then you can be sure.  If authentication is not an option, see [this question for some ideas about making it harder (but not impossible) for someone to imitate your client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17180570/2062384).

> 2) How can I secure data transfer ? Is data transfer using a https (SSL) url sufficient ?

Yes.  Use HTTPS/SSL/TLS.  This provides both confidentiality and integrity through encryption.

> 3) What is the best idea to implement user authentication ? Generate a token to use in communication ? Something else ?

A token is a good choice.  See [this question for some information about token implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15490265/2062384).  This is for a RESTful service but basic approach is the same.

Comment: Thank you ! Lots of the link you propose suggest to use HMAC for authentication. However, such a "protocol" implies the existence of a secret key. The problem is that Phonegap app source is not secure, isn't it ? How can I store that key ?

Comment: @user1553136 The secret key should not be stored other than the minimum time it takes for the calculation.  The key should be provided by the server as it's needed, because as you allude to, it is not secure if stored on the client.